# mysqli_query() returns empty results for full table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making a page that queries a table for all columns of all results ordered by entry time in descending order with a limit.  When I query for a count of the rows, the query works just fine, but when I try to query the table again for data, I don't get anything.  I decided to try cutting the query down to `"SELECT * FROM comments"` but I still got no results when `"SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM comments"` just beforehand worked.  I've tried using mysqli_error(), but that didn't give me any information.

The query doesn't seem to be failing as the result from mysqli_query() isn't false and when I query in phpMyAdmin, the queries work.  A little piece of my code below

```
//open databases
require_once($root . "databases/data.php");

//get number of suggestions in comments table
$cquery = mysqli_query($cbase, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM comments"); //this works
$c = mysqli_fetch_array($cquery);
$count = $c["count"];

//get all suggestions
//this query fails
$queryText = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT " . (($page - 1) * $pageLimit) . ", " . $pageLimit;
$query = mysqli_query($cbase, $queryText);

//validate query
if($query === false)
{
    $failed = true;
}

//get all comments from query
while(!$failed && $array = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

Comment: So what are the values of `$page` and `$pageLimit`?

Comment: `echo` your `$queryText` and show that to us. @MarkBaker is probably correct with his hunch that `$page` & `$pageLimit` are messed up.

Comment: My apologies.  `$page` should be 1 first time and `$pageLimit` should always be 40.  `$queryText` holds `"SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0, 40"`

Comment: Even using `"SELECT * FROM comments"` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this on line 3

```
$c = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cquery);
```

You can also try like this also,

```
$c = mysqli_fetch_array($cquery, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just using the wrong variable when reading out your query results in your while-loop. `mysqli_fetch_array($result)` while you saved the query-result in $query so it should be `mysqli_fetch_array($query)`

Comment: I can't check this code anymore, but this is probably the correct answer. What an oversight on my part.

Comment: I now realise I was answering an 2+ year old question... :S Most likely popped up in SO's main overview after Saran's answer